# How to align 2 images by their centre using JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, css, alignment

I have 2 images, one of them has a Mask area. And the other image can be seen through the Masked area of the above image. I want to centre the second image within the Mask area of the first image.

Currently I'm do scale the image to mach with the mask area using below function (It has 3 lines of code that I tried to with alignment - didnt work though),

```
function scaleimage(img){

    img.style.height = 'auto';
    img.style.width = 'auto';

   //Getting the image hight and width
    var imgW = img.clientWidth;
    var imgH = img.clientHeight;

   //Getting the mask hight and width
    var maskH = data.result.mask.maskhight;
    var maskW = data.result.mask.maskwidth;

    var scaleH = maskH / imgH;
    var scaleW = maskW / imgW;

   // Scaling
    if (scaleH < scaleW) {
        img.style.height = maskH + "px";
        img.style.width = Math.round(imgW * scaleH) + "px";
    } else {
        img.style.width = maskW + "px";
        img.style.height = Math.round(imgH * scaleW) + "px";
    }

      //Align image - commented below code since it didnt work

  /*img.style.top = Math.round((mask1H - imgH) / 2) + 'px';
    img.style.left = '50%';
    img.style.marginLeft = Math.round(imgW/2) + 'px'; */

}
```

Current and Expected result as an Illustration. IMAGE 1 has a Mask area that can see through, and IMAGE 2 is behind IMAGE 1, but align its top left to the Mask Area's Top left. What I want is, IMAGE 2 centre = Mask Area Centre

[image]

I tried few things and didn't get any of them quite right, any feedback would be really helpful

Comment: whats happening right now? is the 2 images on top of each other? or side by side? is it same size?

Comment: I have updated my question with an Illustration, with what happening now and whats expected. Please have a look.

Comment: Would it be possible to set up a fiddle with your markup, your CSS and your code?

Comment: i think it depends on how you call them in your page.  On a site where I did this I used nested divs with the inner element being the smaller one with margins of half the difference.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly from your code. You want to resize image to fix into your mask. I have write a demo using your function [here](http://jsbin.com/oxeciy/1/). Because I dont know your real HTML, I use my own code with a predefined value of `maskW` and `maskH`.

Another thing to note: you should set the `position` property of the image style to another value than the default `static` value if you want to layout it manually. In the demo, I set the `position` value of `img` element to `absolute`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a css solution for this if you'd like to try:

Html:

```
<div>
    <img class="image" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/0000ff/ffffff&text=image" alt="image">
</div>
```

Css:

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/150x100/000/fff&text=mask) no-repeat center center;
}
.image {
    width: 80%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -27% 0 0 -40%;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxPcm/)**

Comment: Good stuff, but my IMAGE 2 loads dynamically and it can be any image with different widths, highs and orientation. Not sure  how it works for a image that loads dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two approaches here:

- use negative left margin of second image

  ```
  <img id="img"/><img id="mask"/>
  <script>
  mask.style.marginLeft = (imgW + maskW) / -2;
  mask.style.marginTop = (imgH - maskH) / 2;
  </script>
  ```
- show images as background of two divs (one embeds another). Set their width and height same values (of bigger image) and use center alignment of inner background. But then, if you're getting images by AJAX, you should retrieve also sizes of the images.

  ```
  <div id="img">
      <div id="mask"></div>
  </div>
  <style>
  #img {
      background-position: top left;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  #mask {
      width: inherit;
      height: inherit;
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  </style>
  <script>
  var imgDiv = document.getElementsById('img'),
      maskDiv = document.getElementById('mask');
  imgDiv.style.width = imgW + 'px'; // from AJAX
  imgDiv.style.height = imgH + 'px';
  imgDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('img.jpg')"';
  maskDiv.style.backgroundImage = "url('mask.jpg')";
  </script>
  ```

*This is juts an idea and should work with fixes*